# Create Word file from Excel 2011

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2011

The usual approach to create a Word document from Excel VBA:

```
Set WD = CreateObject("Word.Document")
```

results in an error when run with Excel 2011.

Any idea how a Word document can be created in Excel 2011 with VBA?

(I do not want to use AppleScript as I want the program to be able to run on PCs also.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The very first thing you should do when you write the words "results in an error" or "causes an exception" is to post the **exact** meaning of "an error" or the **exact** exception or error message you received. Please remember that we only have the information you provide in your question to go by - we can't see your screen or your code or your error message from here. The more information you provide us to work with, the more chances there are of you getting an answer (and the quicker, too). In other words, you need to help us help you. :)

Comment: http://forum.soft32.com/mac/Error-ActiveX-create-object-OSX-ftopict83351.html

Comment: This approach causes me to get an Out of Memory error, which makes no sense to me...  On a Mac and using VBA.

Answer (score 2):

The following code, based on the suggestion by bretville, seems to work both on mac (tested on Excel2011) and on pc (tested on Excel2007) and can be run repetedly, thus allowing creation of multiple Word files. What is required for the code to work under Excel2011 (mac) vba is a means to test if Word already is running or not. The approach is perhaps not the most elegant, but it works.

```
Dim word As Object
Dim doc As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set word = GetObject(, "word.application") 'gives error 429 if Word is not open
If Err = 429 Then
    Set word = CreateObject("word.application") 'creates a Word application
    Err.Clear
End If
word.Visible = True
Set doc = word.documents.Add
```

You may interchange the two Set word statements, which might seem preferable as no error code handling becomes necessary when run on pc, but the code for some reason then runs terribly slowly on the mac.

Answer (score 0):

For a PC I would do this:

```
Dim word As Object: Set word = CreateObject("word.application")
word.Visible = True
Dim doc As Object: Set doc = word.documents.Add
```

Comment: Thanks, @brettville, your code works OK for the first run with Excel2011, thus proving that it should be possible to create word files. However, run a second time or with Word already open, the statement      Set word = CreateObject("word.application")  gives error 429 (object cannot be created by ActiveX component) on the mac although it runs without problem on pc (Excel 2007)/Rolf

Comment: Hm, in Excel VBA for the mac, do you have the ability to add references?

Comment: How would I know? Excel 2011 vba comes without any usable (searchable) help system! What approach to the problem do you have in mind?